# Document is being deleted after modifying via Java bean

Tags: java, javabeans, xpages, xpages-ssjs

Scenario: I want a generic way to create reader and author fields in my (new) document data source on an XPage. My approach now is to hand over the document to a bean method in the postSaveDocument event from the data source. The method can also be set to saving the document or not, depending on the event that will be called (e.g. the querySaveDocument event).
The items that are checked and set within my method are set in the postNewDocument event of my data source. Strangely the document is not saved resp. deleted after the bean method is called. I am very surprised... Do you have any ideas, what is happening here?

postNewDocument event code:

```
document1.setValue("$rnaAuthors", "Foo")
document1.setValue("Foo", "Bar")
```

postSaveDocument event code:

```
rna.save(document1.getDocument(true), true)
```

The bean is configured in my faces-config.xml:

```
<managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>rna</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.olb.ReadWriteAccess
        </managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
```

This is the bean code:

```
package com.olb;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Vector;

import lotus.domino.Document;
import lotus.domino.Item;
import lotus.domino.NotesException;

public class ReadWriteAccess implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void save(Document doc, boolean saveIt) {
        try {
            // check if special items exist
            if (!doc.hasItem("$rnaReaders") && !doc.hasItem("$rnaAuthors"))
                return;

            // now fetch all the items by name and set the property
            Vector v = doc.getItemValue("$rnaReaders");
            for (int x = 0; x < v.size(); x++) {
                Item it = doc.getFirstItem(v.elementAt(x).toString());
                if (it != null) {
                    if (!it.isReaders())
                        it.setReaders(true);
                }
            }
            v = doc.getItemValue("$rnaAuthors");
            for (int x = 0; x < v.size(); x++) {
                Item it = doc.getFirstItem(v.elementAt(x).toString());
                if (it != null) {
                    if (!it.isReaders())
                        it.setReaders(true);
                }
            }

            if (saveIt) {
                doc.save();
            }

        } catch (NotesException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                if (saveIt) {
                    doc.replaceItemValue("$rnaError", e.getMessage());
                    doc.save();
                }
            } catch (Exception e2) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check in database properties: does number of documents increment after that?

Comment: No the number does not increase. The error I get after hitting my save button second time is clear: "document has been deleted".

Comment: Try to change scope from view to request.

Comment: Changed scope to "request" and followed stwissels suggestions. Same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are setting a reader field instead of an author field. The XPages engine tries to restore the document, but is unable to find it. That's why the *"document has been deleted"* error is thrown after the second time you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid save operations that run twice (e.g. PostSave -> XPages saved the document, and you save again), Stick to QuerySave and hand over the document only. You need to `recycle()` your items, otherwise your bean bleeds C objects. Switch to, as Frantisek suggested, to request scope.

Comment: Changed scope to "request" and recycled the items. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

Sven Hasselbach got it - my fault. Here is the correct code for you:

```
package com.olb;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Vector;

import lotus.domino.Document;
import lotus.domino.Item;
import lotus.domino.NotesException;

public class ReadWriteAccess implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void save(Document doc, boolean saveIt) {
        try {
            // check if special items exist
            if (!doc.hasItem("$rnaReaders") && !doc.hasItem("$rnaAuthors"))
                return;

            // now fetch all the items by name and set the property
            Vector v = doc.getItemValue("$rnaReaders");
            for (int x = 0; x < v.size(); x++) {
                Item it = doc.getFirstItem(v.elementAt(x).toString());
                if (it != null) {
                    if (!it.isReaders())
                        it.setReaders(true);
                }
            }
            v = doc.getItemValue("$rnaAuthors");
            for (int x = 0; x < v.size(); x++) {
                Item it = doc.getFirstItem(v.elementAt(x).toString());
                if (it != null) {
                    if (!it.isAuthors())
                        it.setAuthors(true);
                }
            }

            if (saveIt) {
                doc.save();
            }

        } catch (NotesException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                if (saveIt) {
                    doc.replaceItemValue("$rnaError", e.getMessage());
                    doc.save();
                }
            } catch (Exception e2) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```